# Sluggable behavior Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

When I use Sluggable Behavior on my localhost it works as expected, but when I upload that same code to online server, it doesn't work at all(slug attribute is empty in the database). How can I possibly know what went wrong?

So this method in SiteController works as expected on localhost.

```
public function actionTest(){
    $attr = 'Lorem ipsum';
    var_dump(Inflector::slug($attr));
    die();
}
```

But that same method returns nothing on live server. var_dump gives string""(0)

Comment: Please post your Sample code

Comment: @Unknown I updated my question. And also want to say that when I use for example Inflector::humanize($attr) it works as expected on live server, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[intl PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) and [ICU](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classMessageFormat.html) (*>= v49*) are both required by [Inflector::slug()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseinflector.html#slug()-detail). read about it more in the [Internationalization - setup-environment section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html#setup-environment) of the Yii2 official docs.

Also check the `requirement.php` file output so you can know if any other required lib is missing.